# How to make images in grid responsive in mobile/smaller view?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, image-resizing

Im trying to make images resizable/responsive and Ive been trying everything-setting the image surrounding div to a par. size in px and giving the images a percentage as well as all kind of other things like min/max-width, looked up solutions online etc but nothing works. Any ideas?

html:

```
<section id="skills" class=" skillsSection">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row skillsHeader">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div class="vertical">
                    <h3 class="H2">
                 <span>SKILLS</span>
                 </h3>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row skillsRow">

            <div class="col-md-3 skills-item wow zoomIn">
                <img src="images/..." class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 skills-item wow zoomIn">
                <img src="images/..." class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 skills-item wow zoomIn">
              <img src="images/..." class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 skills-item wow zoomIn">
                <img src="images/..." class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 skills-item wow zoomIn">
                <img src="images/..." class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 skills-item wow zoomIn">
                <img src="images/..." class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 skills-item wow zoomIn">
                <img src="images/..." class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

css:

```
skills-item img {
  width: 50px;
}

.img-responsive{
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at using Bootstrap?

Comment: you could use @media(max-width: 400px){/*CSS goes here*/} or something like that. However, JavaScript can be really good to use for this, too.

Comment: I just tried it and then gave omg-responsive a small width (12%) and said float:left so the omg still appear inline but it doesn't work either. the omg just get larger instead of smaller